Regularity of a sequence with terms in Sobolev space
Let $M: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ a function of class $C_{0}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{N}\right)$ defined by
$\bullet$ $M(x) = 1$, se $x \in B_1(0)$;
$\bullet$ $M(x) = 0$, se $x \in \mathbb{R}^N \setminus B_2(0)$.
In particular, for each $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$, define the sequence
$$u_n(x) := M_n(x) u(x),$$
where $M_n(x) = M(x/n)$. Can you conclude that $u_n \in C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^N)$? If not, is it possible to define $M$ in a more specific way to conclude this fact?

In general, we cannot conclude that $u_n \in C^{\infty}_0$. Indeed, $M_n \equiv 1$ on the ball of radius $1/n$ and as such $u_n = u$ on $B_{1/n}$. Thus $u_n$ is only as regular as $u$ on this set.
If you wish to "regularize" the function $u$, you might be interested in considering mollifications (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier).
